# Is it acceptable to resurrect old threads with new answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

I was browsing the main site and came across this [veteran 1.5 year old question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2/is-a-fumble-on-a-natural-1-an-official-rule), and I feel that I have a useful answer to add - a house-rule interpretation that hasn't been brought up in the current set of answers and comments.

Is it acceptable practice here on RPG.SE to add a new answer, even though there hasn't been any activity on it for months?

Comment: One side note to @waxeagles excellent answer, not every old question on the site would be considered kosher.  We've tried to close the stuff that wouldn't fly now, but you may answer some old questions of certain types just to see it closed.  See the [FAQ].

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Absolutely.

There are even badges for it. Necromancer, Revival, Excavator, Archaeologist all reward you for going back to old posts and doing something (necromancer and revival for answering and excavator and archaeologist for editing.

If there isn't a good answer on an old question or you can do better than any previous answer then please provide one. SE questions are designed to be a lasting thing on the Internet and thus we should spend at least a little bit of time maintaining them.

The only caution I would issue is to do it slowly. If you edit/add answer to 10 or 15 new posts it might take a couple of days for them to go off the front page due to our relatively small volume of posts. However doing a couple at a time is a great way to keep old questions fresh and relevant.

Comment: Yes, the SE philosophy is that there are no "old threads" - everything should be evergreened.  If there's ever a new question that duplicates an old one we close it as a dupe.  Answer away!